# In Azure Eventhub receiver giving "Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds" error

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am trying to implement the receiver part as per the tutorial

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-ephjava-getstarted/

```
Failure while registering: com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.EPHConfigurationException:
```

Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds

I have 16 partitions in my eventhub. But when I send the data I don't specify any partition. How do I know in which partition my data is sent to? Am I getting the above error because of all the partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your consumer sas policies does includes "manage" and not only "listen". 
I guess it has to have manage rights to be able to list the partitions.

Comment: I have the same problem. How to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally - EPH should work with "Listen"-only Claims. Right now we have a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/issues/195) in EventProcessorHost client-code as a result of which - it needs "Manage" claims. We are working on it.

The error "Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds" is generic and Thrown at [PartitionManager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/java/azure-eventhubs-eph/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventprocessorhost/PartitionManager.java#L96), while querying for Partitions. You ran into one of the exceptions in the below catch block. Please indicate inner-exception for completeness (SEO) & faster resolution.

```
catch(XPathExpressionException|ParserConfigurationException|IOException|InvalidKeyException|NoSuchAlgorithmException|URISyntaxException|SAXException exception)
{
    throw new EPHConfigurationException("Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds", exception);
}
```

**EDIT:**

this issue is fixed in version [`0.7.7`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs).

Comment: I am still getting this issue as such: `[2023-11-30T21:37:04.138Z] The listener for function 'Functions.TestEventHubTriggerVAP' was unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.). Microsoft.Azure.Amqp: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[2023-11-30T21:37:23.356Z] EventProcessorHost error (Action='Retrieving list of partition identifiers from a Consumer Client.', HostName='f6cb1ca0-bf24-4307-a7ac-20ff12369cb9', PartitionId='').` when starting my app locally from vscode

Answer (score 0):

I was working with integrating eventhub with the ELK stack and came across the same error.
To solve this I found that in the settings for the Event Hub Namespace that my event hub was in I had to allow access to the VNET my ELK stack was in.

This can be done by going to the following page: Your EventHubNamespace > Settings - Firewalls and virtual networks.
Either allow access from all networks or add your specific VNET, Subnet, or IP range (for specific machines).

This in addition to setting consumer sas policies to Manage should resolve the "Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds" error.

Comment: If you can post some sample code then it will of good help to the user.