# Logstash + Azure Events Hubs

Tags: azure, logstash, elastic-stack

Trying to follow the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/azure-module.html#azure_best_practices) to add azure event into logstash, I have the below issue:

```
[2020-02-13T14:06:28,886][ERROR][com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionManager] host logstash-5fdbcee8-e368-44de-bc13-c640a36f646f: Exception while initializing stores, not starting partition manager com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.IllegalEntityException: Failure getting partition ids for event hub
        at com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionManager.lambda$cachePartitionIds$4(PartitionManager.java:80) ~[azure-eventhubs-eph-2.1.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:836) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:811) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_242]
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I will share the config process

Comment: Thanks, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the hint from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505786/in-azure-eventhub-reciever-giving-encountered-error-while-fetching-the-list-of). It appears the consumer SAS policy still needs manage privileges.