# While debugging project which has internal dependency on the Azure component , I am getting error related to partition id

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, partition, azure-eventhub

The error states that :"***Exception User-Unhandled
Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorConfigurationException: 'Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub Partitionids'
Inner Exception
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a va period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.***"

First time I am not getting this exception after clearing the cache and restarting my laptop . Post that same issue occurs . Is there any way to check on this ?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this `Exception User-Unhandled Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorConfigurationException: 'Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub Partitionids' Inner Exception SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a va period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."` error, try the following way:

As suggested by [MayankBargali](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/502226/issue-debugin-azure-function-v3-core-31-with-event.html), check whether the required port is open or not.

- Make sure to open ports `443/5671/5672`
- You can use the [PortQry tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=24009) to query your eventhub namespace on these ports to confirm if these are blocked or not.

References: [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor: Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/issues/360) and [In Azure Eventhub reciever giving "Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505786/in-azure-eventhub-reciever-giving-encountered-error-while-fetching-the-list-of)